# Displaying results from LINQ query in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller that contains a LINQ query. My query looks something like the following:

```
var posts = GetBlogPosts();
var results = from post in posts
              select new
              {
                Title = "This is the blog title",
                Url = "www.google.com",
                Author = "Bill Jones",
                AuthorUrl = "www.billjones.com",
                Description = "This is the description of the post"
              };
ViewBag.Posts = results;
```

I am trying to display the Posts in my view. Currently, I have the following:

```
@foreach (var post in ViewBag.Posts)
{
  <div class="postBody">
    <h1 class="blogTitle">@post.Title</h1>
    <p class="blogInfo">@post.Description</p>
  </div>
}
```

When I execute this, I receive an error at runtime. My error says:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because this portion of your code is selecting an anonymous object.  The view has no idea what type of object that is.  Your Viewbag is a dynamic object as well and will not tell the view what specific type of object is located within it.

```
          select new
          {
            Title = "This is the blog title",
            Url = "www.google.com",
            Author = "Bill Jones",
            AuthorUrl = "www.billjones.com",
            Description = "This is the description of the post"
          };
```

Most likely you can do the following

```
 ViewBag.Posts = GetBlogPosts();
```

In your view you would do this:

```
@foreach (var post in (IEnumerable<Post>)ViewBag.Posts)
{
  <div class="postBody">
    <h1 class="blogTitle">@post.Title</h1>
    <p class="blogInfo">@post.Description</p>
  </div>
}
```

Or better yet create a strongly typed view by putting the following at the top of your page

```
 @model IEnumerable<Post>
```

In your controller you return 
     View(GetBlogPosts());

And in your view you do

```
@foreach (var post in Model)
{
  <div class="postBody">
    <h1 class="blogTitle">@post.Title</h1>
    <p class="blogInfo">@post.Description</p>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Where should 'Post" definition go? I created a class in the Models folder. However, my .cshtml file still can't find it. I get an error that says: "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Post' could not be found..."

Comment: You can just use the full namespace and type name that is returned from GetBlogPosts()  So for example if your GetBlogPosts() returns a List<YourProject.NameSpace.Post> then put @Model List<YourProject.NameSpace.Post>

Answer (score 0):

You Can use *Partial View* instead of using ViewBag becuase ViewBag. You need to create new Action inside your controller then call the action from Parent view using HTML.RenderAction as following
1- Create New Action to contain the Linq code

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ViewResult GetPosts()
    {
    var posts = GetBlogPosts();
    var results = from post in posts
                  select new
                  {
                    Title = "This is the blog title",
                    Url = "www.google.com",
                    Author = "Bill Jones",
                    AuthorUrl = "www.billjones.com",
                    Description = "This is the description of the post"
                  };
    return PartialView("ViewName,posts); // the partial view name ,with posts object
}
```

2- Now Create a Partial View with *strongly-typed view* of (Posts) type  and give it any name then write your code as you did with little changes.

```
@model IEnumerable<Post>
@foreach (var post in Model)
{
  <div class="postBody">
    <h1 class="blogTitle">@post.Title</h1>
    <p class="blogInfo">@post.Description</p>
  </div>
}
```

3- Now in your Parent view add HTML.RenderAction ass following

```
    <html>
<head>/<head>
    <body>
    ...
    <div>
    @ { Html.RenderAction("GetPosts");  }  <!--ActionName -->
    </div>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

for more information you can check the following links

[ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

[How to Use the ASP.NET MVC Render Action Helpers](http://devproconnections.com/development/how-use-aspnet-mvc-render-action-helpers)

[Strongly Typed Views in MVC](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/strongly-typed-views-in-mvc/)

[RenderPartial vs RenderAction vs Partial vs Action in MVC Razor](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/Q8V2130113-RenderPartial-vs-RenderAction-vs-Partial-vs-Action-in-MVC-Razor.html)

[When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData](http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications)

I Hope that help